# angularjs autosave form is it the right way?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, restangular

My goal is to autosave a form after is valid and update it with timeout.
I set up like:

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('nodblog.api.article', ['restangular'])
        .config(function (RestangularProvider) {
            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api');
            RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
                id: "_id"
            });
            RestangularProvider.setRequestInterceptor(function(elem, operation, what) {
                if (operation === 'put') {
                    elem._id = undefined;
                    return elem;
                }
                return elem;
            }); 
        })
        .provider('Article', function() {
            this.$get = function(Restangular) {
                function ngArticle() {};
                ngArticle.prototype.articles = Restangular.all('articles');
                ngArticle.prototype.one = function(id) {
                    return Restangular.one('articles', id).get();
                };
                ngArticle.prototype.all = function() {
                    return this.articles.getList();
                };
                ngArticle.prototype.store = function(data) {
                    return this.articles.post(data);
                };
                ngArticle.prototype.copy = function(original) {
                    return  Restangular.copy(original);
                };
                return new ngArticle;
            }
    })
})(window, angular);

angular.module('nodblog',['nodblog.route'])
.directive("autosaveForm", function($timeout,Article) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var id = null;
            scope.$watch('form.$valid', function(validity) {
                if(validity){
                    Article.store(scope.article).then(
                        function(data) {
                            scope.article = Article.copy(data);
                            _autosave();
                        }, 
                        function error(reason) {
                            throw new Error(reason);
                        }
                    );
                }  
            })
            function _autosave(){
                    scope.article.put().then(
                    function() {
                        $timeout(_autosave, 5000); 
                    },
                    function error(reason) {
                        throw new Error(reason);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
})

.controller('CreateCtrl', function ($scope,$location,Article) {
        $scope.article = {};
        $scope.save = function(){
            if(typeof $scope.article.put === 'function'){
                $scope.article.put().then(function() {
                    return $location.path('/blog');
                });
            }
            else{
                Article.store($scope.article).then(
                    function(data) {
                        return $location.path('/blog');
                    }, 
                    function error(reason) {
                        throw new Error(reason);
                    }
                );
            }
        };
     })
```

I'm wondering if there is a best way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because code review questions should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looking at the code I can see is that the $watch will not be re-fired if current input is valid and the user changes anything that is valid too. This is because watch functions are only executed if the value has changed.
You should also check the dirty state of the form and reset it when the form data has been persisted otherwise you'll get an endless persist loop.

And your not clearing any previous timeouts.

And the current code will save invalid data if a current timeout is in progress.

I've plunked a directive which does this all and has better [SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) so it can be reused. Just provide it a callback expression and you're good to go.

[See it in action in this plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/FUy2tn?p=preview)

**Demo Controller**

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.form = {
    state: {},
    data: {}
  };

  $scope.saveForm = function() {
    console.log('Saving form data ...', $scope.form.data);  
  };

});
```

**Demo Html**

```
  <div ng-controller="MyController">

    <form name="form.state" auto-save-form="saveForm()">

      <div>
        <label>Numbers only</label>
        <input name="text" 
               ng-model="form.data.text" 
               ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"/>
      </div>

      <span ng-if="form.state.$dirty && form.state.$valid">Updating ...</span>      

    </form>
  </div>
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('autoSaveForm', function($timeout) {

  return {
    require: ['^form'],
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrls) {

      var $formCtrl = $ctrls[0];
      var savePromise = null;
      var expression = $attrs.autoSaveForm || 'true';

      $scope.$watch(function() {

        if($formCtrl.$valid && $formCtrl.$dirty) {

          if(savePromise) {
            $timeout.cancel(savePromise);
          }

          savePromise = $timeout(function() {

            savePromise = null;

            // Still valid?

            if($formCtrl.$valid) {

              if($scope.$eval(expression) !== false) {
                console.log('Form data persisted -- setting prestine flag');
                $formCtrl.$setPristine();  
              }

            }

          }, 500);
        }

      });
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is nice. *Have you added any other features to this directive that you'd care to share?* I'll probably set my timer a little higher, so perhaps I should short-circuit the watch for a portion of the timer period to prevent `$rootscope.$digest` on every keystroke? Also maybe a `validateAndSaveNow` type of function is appropriate to handle `beforeNavigate` events. Coordination with `angular-loading-bar` could be nice. I can replace the usual `revertForm` function wired to a cancel button with a `setBack` operation, and `PATCH`ing rather than full `POST` would happen in `save()`...

Comment: Hmm, also, how to deal with simultaneous edits without putting the manual UI operations (that autosave is intended to eliminate) right back into the UI? I suppose entering a field sends a lock request. Don't mind me, I'll just keep adding my thoughts here. ;)

Comment: Here's one with a very similar approach to yours that includes a few other ideas and resolves a few issues: http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/10/30/auto-save-your-model-in-angular-js-with-watch-and-debounce/ Part of that post is from before your answer, and part after, so I didn't know who to credit :D

Comment: @shannon
_"Part of that post is from before your answer, and part after, so I didn't know who to credit"_. I'm not quite sure but are you suggesting that I stole the "credits" of that post? Besides, the code doesn't look remotely the same to me.
_"I'll probably set my timer a little higher, ... to prevent $rootscope.$digest on every keystroke?"_. You'll get a `$digest` on every keystroke when you set `ng-model` on an input element, the timer isn't changing anything about that.

Comment: No, not suggesting it at all. I'm suggesting that you both had fundamentally similar approaches, and I was trying to avoid, for the sake of the author of this other code I'd found, implying that the other author's work had no value. (Peace, man.)

Comment: And, yes, the timer does change that, if you short-circuit the watch (the part of the quote you omitted) when the timer is created. The resolution of the hold-off suffers, but adjusting the hold-off resolution (which would then directly determine the frequency of digests) can be separate from adjusting the hold-off. Make sense?

Comment: I've been using this for a couple of years but recently have noticed AngularJS generating an "infinite digest" error - I think because of the cancelling and creating a new $timeout. I guess something changed so one or both of those generate a new digest. I've added a new answer with a slightly modified variation of this directive that hopefully avoids that issue.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
to stopping timeout
all the logic in the directive

```
.directive("autosaveForm", function($timeout,$location,Post) {
    var promise;
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.post = {};
            $scope.save = function(){
                console.log(promise);
                $timeout.cancel(promise);
                if(typeof $scope.post.put === 'function'){
                    $scope.post.put().then(function() {
                        return $location.path('/post');
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Post.store($scope.post).then(
                        function(data) {
                            return $location.path('/post');
                        }, 
                        function error(reason) {
                            throw new Error(reason);
                        }
                    );
                }
            };

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('form.$valid', function(validity) {
                element.find('#status').removeClass('btn-success');
                element.find('#status').addClass('btn-danger');
                if(validity){
                    Post.store(scope.post).then(
                        function(data) {
                            element.find('#status').removeClass('btn-danger');
                            element.find('#status').addClass('btn-success');
                            scope.post = Post.copy(data);
                            _autosave();
                        }, 
                        function error(reason) {
                            throw new Error(reason);
                        }
                    );
                }  
            })
            function _autosave(){
                    scope.post.put().then(
                    function() {
                        promise = $timeout(_autosave, 2000);
                    },
                    function error(reason) {
                        throw new Error(reason);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: if you want to **update** your question, just edit the original one. Don't post an answer... that is, unless you're answering your own question, but then write your answer as an answer, not an update

Comment: sorry next time I'll follow your tip.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of Null's directive, created because I started seeing "Infinite $digest Loop" errors. (I suspect something changed in Angular where cancelling/creating a $timeout() now triggers a digest.)

This variation uses a proper $watch expression - watching for the form to be dirty and valid - and then calls $setPristine() earlier so the watch will re-fire if the form transitions to dirty again. We then use an $interval to wait for a pause in those dirty notifications before saving the form.

```
app.directive('autoSaveForm', function ($log, $interval) {

  return {
    require: ['^form'],
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

      var $formCtrl = controllers[0];
      var autoSaveExpression = attrs.autoSaveForm;
      if (!autoSaveExpression) {
        $log.error('autoSaveForm missing parameter');
      }

      var savePromise = null;
      var formModified;

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $interval.cancel(savePromise);
      });

      scope.$watch(function () {
        // note: formCtrl.$valid is undefined when this first runs, so we use !$formCtrl.$invalid instead
        return !$formCtrl.$invalid && $formCtrl.$dirty;
      }, function (newValue, oldVaue, scope) {

        if (!newValue) {
          // ignore, it's not "valid and dirty"
          return;
        }

        // Mark pristine here - so we get notified again if the form is further changed, which would make it dirty again
        $formCtrl.$setPristine();

        if (savePromise) {
          // yikes, note we've had more activity - which we interpret as ongoing changes to the form.
          formModified = true;
          return;
        }

        // initialize - for the new interval timer we're about to create, we haven't yet re-dirtied the form
        formModified = false;

        savePromise = $interval(function () {

          if (formModified) {
            // darn - we've got to wait another period for things to quiet down before we can save
            formModified = false;
            return;
          }

          $interval.cancel(savePromise);
          savePromise = null;

          // Still valid?

          if ($formCtrl.$valid) {

            $formCtrl.$saving = true;
            $log.info('Form data persisting');

            var autoSavePromise = scope.$eval(autoSaveExpression);
            if (!autoSavePromise || !autoSavePromise.finally) {
              $log.error('autoSaveForm not returning a promise');
            }

            autoSavePromise
            .finally(function () {
              $log.info('Form data persisted');
              $formCtrl.$saving = undefined;
            });
          }
        }, 500);

      });
    }
  };

});
```