# AutoSave on Angular project with very large forms

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, autosave

I am currently working on a `JHipster` generated `Angular + Spring` project.

We have very large forms with dozens of fields each, which are not declared with a markup such as `<form>`, but enclosed in `divs` such as this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label">Search Publication by id: </label>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <div class="input-group">
                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="surveyDataId"-->
                       <!--ww-enter="searchSurveyData()">-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="publicationId"
                       placeholder="Search"
                       uib-typeahead="publication.id as publication.id + ', ' +publication.title+ ', ' +publication.firstAuthor for publication in publications | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:15"
                       typeahead-editable="false" ww-enter="searchPublication()">
```

The js part is all separated in several controllers for each html view

Now, the problem I'm facing with such implementation comes when trying to autosave the form.

I have tried several solutions:

http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/10/30/auto-save-your-model-in-angular-js-with-watch-and-debounce/  -> No good as I can't put watch on to each input field having so many

[angularjs autosave form is it the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135302/angularjs-autosave-form-is-it-the-right-way)  -> No good as the form is made up of several html files, not a single markup with form in the whole project

https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-auto-save-form  -> Same issue as before

[Sisyphus](https://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/) -> Very unclear documentation, tried implementing by script tags, but no joy

`ng-blur` and `ng-change` are not a valid option either for obvious reasons

I would appreciate any recomendations

Comment: Were are you attempting to save the form data to? Writing to a database, browser local storage, etc? Are you asking about the actual storage, or just the process getting to your existing storage solution?

Comment: Database hosted on external server

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save together multiple objects across different controllers, then you would be better off having the data saved in a factory, which is then injected into the controllers that need it.

In a factory, you could create a single object which houses the data for each of the html pages or form partials that you have. The factory can also house the functionality to auto-save or otherwise manipulate that data. Each controller would then inject the factory and modify its portion of the data object.  From the controller, on-change/debounce/watchers could call functions from the factory and perform any needed data manipulation.

Comment: Sounds promising, I will try to give it a go and let you know, thanks for advice!